# django-rest-framework auto generate html id / css

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to assign css styling to html generated by the django-rest-framework.

Rendering a form in django generates html where the html controls have an id based on the form field name.  The documentation that describes that is in the "Form rendering options" section of the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/

I'm using the id to assign css styling to html controls.

Is there similar functionality in django-rest-frammework ?  I am rendering an object using a template (code below) but the html does not have any id tags.

'''

```
@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes([TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer])
def snippet_detail (request, pk, format=None):
    snippet = django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404 (Snippet, pk=pk)
    if request.accepted_renderer.format == 'html':
        return Response({'serializer':SnippetSerializer (snippet), 'snippet':snippet}, template_name='company.html')

    serializer = SnippetSerializer (instance = snippet)
    return Response (serializer.data)
```

'''

Is there  another way to assign css to the html generated by django-rest-framework?

Thanks.

Comment: you trying to add html attributes like css, placeholder,... to the django form field? is that right ?

Comment: The goal is to add css attributes to the html generated by the DRF response line:  

 return Response({'serializer':SnippetSerializer (snippet), 'snippet':snippet}, template_name='company.html')  

The HTML that is produced by that command has elements (i.e. 

 <input name="title" class="form-control" type="text"  value="Say Hi function" >  

As far  as I know,  there is no way to reference that  in CSS.  

Thanks.